# iOS Share extension - the loadItemForTypeIdentifier call returns file url in iOS11 and file content in iOS12

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, share-extension

I see different behavior on iOS 11 vs 12.

On iOS 11 - I get the filepath of files shared in completion handler.

On iOS 12 - I get a URL domain error. But if i handle it based on the type (eg: UIImage), then I get the file content.

Is this behaviour only on simulator or on device as well ?

Do we need to handle this per iOS version ?

Answer (score 0):

## Yes you will get both thing (file path or data) on device also. You did not need to add any check on iOS version.

### Please flow my code. It is in swift but you can understand it.

```
func share() {
let inputItem = extensionContext!.inputItems.first! as! NSExtensionItem
let attachment = inputItem.attachments!.first as! NSItemProvider
if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier( kUTTypeImage as String) {
    attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String, options: [:]) { (data, error) in
        var image: UIImage?
        if let someURl = data as? URL {
            image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: someURl.path)
        }else if let someImage = data as? UIImage {
            image = someImage
        }
        
        if let someImage = image {
            guard let compressedImagePath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("shareImage.jpg", isDirectory: false) else {
                return
            }
            
            let compressedImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(someImage, 1)
            guard (try? compressedImageData?.write(to: compressedImagePath)) != nil else {
                return
            }
            
        }else{
            print("bad share data")
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am doing it in objective C. And I see the difference in the value in the 'data' argument with 11 vs 12. Seems very unusual. Has anyone experienced this ?